# Changing datatype in avro schema

Tags: hive, avro

I want to change the datatype of one column in avro schema.
I want to know if we change datatype, does the data be preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Data will be preserved in the store but, when changing schema in the store, some error checking is performed to ensure that schema evolution can be performed correctly. This error checking consists of comparing the new schema to all currently enabled versions of that schema.

This error checking can result in either Errors or Warnings. Errors are fatal problems that must be addressed before the modified schema can be added to the store. Errors represent situations where data written with an old version of the schema cannot be read by clients using a new version of the schema.